# Regarding the shortest path connecting two points on a sphere of radius $R$

Tags: integration, mathematical-physics, euler-lagrange-equation

Consider a path on the surface of the sphere given by a function $\phi(\theta)$. The line element along the path $\phi$ is given by
$$
\mathrm{d}s=R\mathrm{d}\theta\sqrt{1+\left (\frac{ \mathrm{d} \phi}{\mathrm{d} \theta}\right )^2\sin^2\theta}.
$$
Deriving the Euler-Lagrange equation for $\phi(\theta)$, they lead to the differential equation
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} \phi}{\mathrm{d} \theta}=\frac{c}{\sin\theta\sqrt{\sin^2\theta-c^2}}\tag{1}
$$
with $c$ some constant. Now, there are two things I'd like to figure out. How do I show that Euler-Lagrange equation is solved by
$$
\phi=\arcsin(C_1\cot\theta),
$$
where $C_1$ is constant? Determining such an integral is difficult for me. I think I should apply the identites identites $(\arcsin x)'=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$ and $(\cot x)'=-\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}$. Secondly, I want to transform $(1)$ into cartesian coordinates, but I am not sure how to do it. Should I use the trigonometric addition formula here?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Yes, this is a pure math question.  If it were in the context of a physics problem, like geodesics in GR, or the path of a moving particle I'd say otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

for your line element:

$\left(\frac{ds}{dt}\right)^2=R^2\,\left(\dot{\vartheta}\right)^2+
R^2\,\sin^2(\vartheta)\left(\dot{\varphi}\right)^2
$

I get this differential equations :

$
\ddot{\vartheta}-\frac{c^2\cos(\vartheta)}{R^4\,m^2\,\sin^3(\vartheta)}=0
$

and
$\dot{\varphi}=\frac{c}{R^2\,m\,\sin^2(\vartheta)}$

There is no analytical solution ?